# Threaded DGEMM on ifort

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I've implemented a working program (FORTRAN, compiler: Intel ifort 11.x) that makes calls to DGEMM. I've read that there's a quick way to parallelize this by compiling with:

```
ifort -mkl=parallel -O3 myprog.f -o myprog
```

I have a quad-core processor, so I run the program with (via bash):

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
./myprog
```

My assumption was that DGEMM would automatically summon 4 threads, resulting in faster matrix multiplication. That doesn't seem to be happening. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you compiling all of the source code with this command?  Try -parallel instead.

Comment: How big are the matrices that you multiply with `DGEMM`? MKL threading is also controlled by the `MKL_NUM_THREADS` variable. Check that it is not set to `1`. By the way, `DGEMM` is a canonical example of the built-in parallelism in MKL - see [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/parallelism-in-the-intel-math-kernel-library).

Comment: I think the matrices were too small. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I think -mkl=parallel is the default choice of the intel compiler. Therefore you don't have to set this flag especially. Try -mkl=sequential instead and see if the calculations are slowing down.